# How to reset row when Excel switches to new sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

EDIT4: More problem. Now, I am stuck on the first Else If statement, even though it should loop through. For some reason, my code gets stuck on that line, and it resets my RowCntr and starts from AssignCurrentVars, where it loops through in order to find a record that has a null value for the 12th column.

```
        Do
    TryCount = 0
AssignCurrentVars:
        'Restart the browser if too many errors occur.
        If TotalFailures = 3 Then
                iret = iim1.iimExit

        End If

For Each ws In Workbooks("ElecOpsCSD_FollowUp_iMacro.xlsm").Worksheets
ws.Select
If ws.Name <> "Control" And ws.Name <> "OutputArchive" And ws.Name <> "CC&B_Process" Then
ws.Activate
If ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(RowCntr, 1).Value <> "" Then
    If ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(RowCntr, 12).Value = "" Then
        Do
                       FieldOrderID = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(RowCntr, 1).Text
                                If Len(FieldOrderID) < 3 Then
                                    FieldOrderID = ""
                                    TryCount = TryCount + 1
                                    If TryCount = 3 Then
                                        GoTo IThinkWereDoneHere
                                    End If
                                End If
                       Status = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(RowCntr, 12).Text



            'User Initiated Stop Point
            If QUITTER = True Then
                MsgBox ("Process Halted by User")
                GoTo IThinkWereDoneHere
            End If

            'Error Handler
            If FieldOrderID = "" Then
                TryCount = TryCount + 1
                RowCntr = RowCntr + 1
                    If TryCount = 3 Then
                        MsgBox ("Encountered records missing Field Order ID. Process Complete.")
                        GoTo IThinkWereDoneHere
                    End If
                GoTo AssignCurrentVars
            End If

            'Skip records that have already been processed, even partially.
            If Status <> "" Then
                RowCntr = RowCntr + 1
                GoTo AssignCurrentVars
            End If

   Loop Until QUITTER = True Or RowCntr = 10000

ElseIf ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(RowCntr, 1).Value <> "" Then
RowCntr = 2
GoTo AssignCurrentVars
ElseIf ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(RowCntr, 12).Value <> "" Then
End If
End If
Workbooks("ElecOpsCSD_FollowUp_iMacro.xlsm").Activate
Next ws

Loop Until ws.Name = "CC&B_Process"
```

Comment: You're running this on a loop, but nothing changes between runs-? You're just calling the VMX subroutine, but with no arguments, so it just does the same thing repeatedly?  It's hard to tell from all that code, but it looks like you're trying to call the same subroutine to run the same code (on the same sheet?) and expecting a different outcome--  The edit looks like a step in the right direction, but it's still calling the same subroutine with no paramaters- it keeps referring to Sheets(i), maybe you're supposed to pass it a sheet index number?

Comment: The sheet index is supposed to change after it finishes running all the records on that sheet. That's what the first sub in the original post is supposed to do, I believe.

Comment: Hmm, I beleive this: Workbooks("ElecOpsCSD_FollowUp_iMacro.xlsm").Activate : needs to be ws.Activate  - at least a place to start.

Comment: The edit works, because it cycles through the sheets,  but I am trying to find how to input my logic in it that tells it to switch from sheet to sheet. Basically, if that status column on the last row is null, then don't switch. If the last row has a non null value for status, then switch. That is where I am having trouble.

Comment: That's a little more clear but I'm still confused - so now you're running a loop which activates each sheet in turn, and then runs the VMX subroutine which acts on the active sheet?  Looking at the code, it keeps refering to sheets(i) and that 'i' wont change between runs, I could be wrong but if that's working so far then that's great.  So now you're stuck on putting in logic where, if a certain cell is null, have it run the code, and if it's not null, have it 'switch' sheets and then run?  Could you be a little more clear?

Comment: Yes, you got it. I apologize for not being clear. I want to look at the column 12 of the last record in the active sheet to put my logic in. If that cell, which holds the completion status for that record, is empty, stay on that sheet and keep working. But, if the cell holds a value (which will state that the record has been completed), then move on to the next sheet.

Comment: So it looks like some progress is being made, to be perfectly honest if you're still stuck I might suggest submitting a new question (You are saying that the VMX code is doing what it's supposed to do, but it's not cycling through sheets, therefore the only problem code is in your WSLoop sub?  If that's right, maybe omit all that VMX code so it's easier to read).  I'll say what's confusing me is this line in vmx, `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Select` .  It's referring to Worksheet(i), but since i isn't declared it should default to zero and it should break..

Comment: If the VMX script runs perfectly each time, and all you're trying to do is get it to NOT RUN when a certain cell on another sheet is filled, I'm sure you're 99% of the way there.  Maybe someone else will be able to interpret this, but for me.. the VMX code NEVER refers to the 'active sheet', it only refers to Sheet(i), which makes me think you need to call VMX with a paramater 'i' that increments.  I just don't get how it's doing anything at all.  For the moment I leave this to a better mind :-) but if I do think of something i'll be sure to comment it

Comment: @Acantud, I changed my question. I feel like we got this. Instead of splitting up, I put all my code in one sub, and it seems to work better. Except, now, I don't when know where to put my reset RowCntr, so it tries to start from the second row when it switches to a new sheet.

Comment: @IXHD Try it right before `Next ws`?  Just reset with `RowCntr = 2`?

Comment: I recommend that as part of debugging, you remove all but the most essential code. The loop will then stare you in the face, and the place where to change the row counter will be obvious.

Comment: @Acantud - I didn't mean to "steal" your answer - you wrote your comment as I wrote my answer. I will delete mine if you post it as yours.

Comment: @Floris Not a problem at all floris...but if it ends up we're wrong, then it's _your_ answer not mine :-)

Comment: How about I thank both of you, @Acantud and @Floris? I stepped through the code really quickly, but it seems to be working now. Thank you both so much, for being patient with me.

Comment: **fanfare** you did 99.98% of it yourself, congrats

Comment: @Acantud, so close, yet so far...

Answer (score 1):

You switch to the next worksheet at the lines

```
Workbooks("ElecOpsCSD_FollowUp_iMacro.xlsm").Activate
Next ws
```

So you might want to set your rowCounter to 1 (or whatever number you want) right there:

```
Workbooks("ElecOpsCSD_FollowUp_iMacro.xlsm").Activate
rowCounter = 1
Next ws
```

Comment: So close, but now it's skipping the records on each sheet once the first row is done. I want it to loop through to see that it doesn't have a status message for rows where there is a value for the first column. It's not doing that anymore. I think I have to change the placement of the RowCntr=2.

Comment: @IXHD it really is tough for me, probably others too, to visualize what your workbook looks like, what's on the sheet you're trying to populate, what's on the sheets it's reading from...  It might be a good idea re-post the question with more description of that layout of the whole thing.  Clearly making progress though-

Comment: @Acantud I think we have it. I had to add a logic to handle that part. This is what I have now...

Comment: 'Step 12a: Reset CC&B. iret = iim1.iimPlay("VH-CCB-reset") Loop Until QUITTER = True Or RowCntr = 10000 ElseIf ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(RowCntr, 12).Value <> "" Then 'Next ws ElseIf ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(RowCntr, 1).Value <> "" Then RowCntr = 2 GoTo AssignCurrentVars End If End If Workbooks("ElecOpsCSD_FollowUp_iMacro.xlsm").Activate 'RowCntr = 2 Next ws Loop Until ws.Name = "CC&B_Process"

Comment: Happy that you found your solution! In general you want to make your code "clean" - in that you want to have a top level loop that is easy to understand and debug, with lower level actions delegated to appropriately-named functions. This is a form of "encapsulation" and it makes for code that is more readable, maintainable, and bug free. Something I think we all strive for.

Comment: @IXHD Floris is right, god help you if you ever have to debug - but you're better now than when you started , and you got the thing working, so celebrate away

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll definitely polish this up, and going forward, I'll try to do a better job of encapsulating. For now, I am still stuck in this code, unfortunately. I am stuck in the new logic I put it in. I can't get out of it for the life of me. I'll post it up as another edit.